# (No frameworks - plain JS) Pagination with JS for a table pulling from API

Tags: javascript, css, web

```
function columnPagination(input){
    var table = document.getElementById("tablePrint");
    var tcolumns = table.getElementsByTagName("th");
    for (var i = 1; i < tcolumns.length; i++){
        td = tcolumns[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].selectColumn;
        if(i > input){
            tcolumns[i].classList.add('hide');
        }else{
            tcolumns[i].classList.remove('hide');
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my `columnPagination` function. I have buttons which call it and give an input. So it renders everything first then allows the user to just filter through the table afterwards. Right now what happens is it hides just the header without the rest of the cells in the column. I want it to hide the entire column.

Is there some CSS or something that I haven't thought of using.

P.S. I'm not using React or Angular because I only know how to build things with frameworks and I don't really know what's actually happening.

Edit: An API passes me a JSON object with the content so I don't know the size of the table or the content.

Thanks for the help everyone! Lots of helpful answers.

Comment: if possible share the screenshot ..

Comment: just a thought, but couldn't you simply paginate by row and not column? does that fit ur usecase?

Comment: I definitely get wanting to know the bare metal and not using a framework, but if you're going to do this kind of advanced selection/modification, I'd use JQuery. It makes this kind of thing MUCH easier. That said though, if I understand the problem, you just want to be able to hide a column. I might go about that differently than what I see here. I'll whip up a "JS Only" example.

Comment: atulquest93 I'll add a screenshot to my next question! It's been resolved.
@Todd Yup, I need to paginate by column for this specific use case. 
TimConsolazio True! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the `td` children of each `tr` and apply the class based on the index to each of those.

```js
function toggleClass(element, className, toSet) {
  element.classList[toSet ? 'add' : 'remove'](className);
}

function columnPagination(input) {
  var table = document.getElementById("tablePrint"),
      dataRows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

  for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
    var cells = dataRows[i].children;
    for (var cell = 0; cell < cells.length; cell++) {
      toggleClass(cells[cell], 'hide', cell == input)
    }
  }
}

columnPagination(1) // 0-based index
```

```css
.hide{color:red}
```

```html
<table id="tablePrint">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head 1</th>
      <th>head 2</th>
      <th>head 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>2.2</td>
      <td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td>3.2</td>
      <td>3.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.1</td>
      <td>4.2</td>
      <td>4.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic example to get you started. Note that I'm using a pretty naive way of identifying table cells (though it does work, I actually have used this technique quite a bit before CSS identifiers became the norm).

You click the blue square on top, it will hide column 1. If you change the code to look for c2, it'll hide column 2. And so on. You can see how you could select and hide/show/style just about anything in a grid this way.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function onClick() {
                var tds = document.getElementsByTagName ( 'td' );
                var arr = Array.from ( tds );
                console.log ( arr );
                arr.forEach ( function ( d ) {
                    if ( d.id.indexOf ( 'c1' ) !== -1 ) {
                        d.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>

        <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: blue; color: white"
             onclick="onClick()">
            Click Me
        </div>

        <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td id="c1_r1">
                    C1_R1
                </td>
                <td id="c2_r1">
                    C2_R1
                </td>
                <td id="c3_r1">
                    C3_R1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="c1_r2">
                    C1_R2
                </td>
                <td id="c2_r2">
                    C2_R2
                </td>
                <td id="c3_r2">
                    C3_R2
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="c1_r3">
                    C1_R3
                </td>
                <td id="c2_r3">
                    C2_R3
                </td>
                <td id="c3_r3">
                    C3_R3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks :)

The table doesn't have to be constant, you can just generate it from JavaScript or whatever backend tech you're using. The only thing you need to do is, inside that script, use some way of naming/tagging the cells so that the ones you want to later operate on can be selected. I usually use "rN_cN", but anything consistent will work. Otherwise the script as written will operate on a table of any size (again as long as it can be selected somehow).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this relatively easily w/ `querySelectorAll` and something like this to start (this is unchecked):

```
let pageSize = 3;
let currentPage = 1; // 1st page

// querySelector method
const getStrQueryForPageRows = function(pageNumber, pageSize=3) {
    let idx = pageSize * (pageNumber - 1);
    return `tr:nth-child(n+${idx}):nth-child(-n+${idx+pageSize})`;
}
const hideColumnOnMyTablePage = (columnNumber, pageNumber) => {
    return document.querySelector('#myTable')
        .querySelectorAll(`${getStrQueryForPageRows(pageNumber)} td:nth-child(${col - 1})`)
        .forEach(col => col.classList.add('hide'))
}

hideColumnOnMyTablePage(2, currentPage) // hide second col of page 1
```

There are also table props that could help you

```
// alt way to grab rows for page
const getMyTableRowsForPage = (pageNumber, pageSize = 3) => {
   let end = pageSize * (pageNumber);
   let start = end - pageSize;
   return [...document.querySelector('#myTable').tBodies[0].rows].slice(start, end);
}
```